# Why do substrings prevent match with negative lookahead?

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

Consider the following test data:

```
x.foo,x.bar
y.foo,y.bar
yy.foo,yy.bar

x.foo,y.bar
y.foo,x.bar
yy.foo,x.bar
x.foo,yy.bar
yy.foo,y.bar
y.foo,yy.bar
```

I'm attempting to write a regular expression where the string before `.foo` and the string before `.bar` are *different* from each other.  The first three items should not match.  The other six should.

This mostly works:

```
^(.+?)\.foo,(?!\1)(.+?)\.bar$
```

However, it misses on the last one, because `y` is in match group 1, and thus `yy` is not matched in match group 2.

Interactive: https://regex101.com/r/Pv5062/1

How can I modify the negative lookahead pattern such that the last item matches as well?

Comment: `^(.+?)\.foo,(?!\1\.)(.+?)\.bar$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline backreferences do not store the context information, they only keep the *text* captured. You need to specify the context yourself.

You may add a dot after `\1`:

```
^(.+?)\.foo,(?!\1\.)(.+?)\.bar$
                 ^^
```

Or, even repeat the part after the second `(.+?)`:

```
^(.+?)\.foo,(?!\1\.bar$)(.+?)\.bar$
```

Or, if the `bar` part cannot contain `.`, you may make it more "generic":

```
^(.+?)\.foo,(?!\1\.[^.]+$)(.+?)\.bar$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gDRKRV/1) and [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gDRKRV/2).

The point is: your `(?!\1)` is not "anchored" and will fail the match in case the text stored in Group 1 appears immediately to the right of the current location *regardless of the context*. To solve this, you need to provide this context. As the value that can be matched with `.+?` can contain virtually anything all you can rely on is the "hardcoded" bits after the lookahead.

Comment: Very helpful.  Thanks for the detailed explanation!